# Proper design for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So you have `Establishments` and `Happies`

Each `Establishment` can have many `Happies`

`Users` can add new `Establishments` and add new `Happies`.

When a `User` goes to add a `Happy` they fill out the form, and they select which `Establishment` the `Happy` belongs to.

Whats the cleanest way for a `User` to choose which `Establishment` the `Happy` belongs to?

i.e. entering in the id of the establishment, drop down menu with establishments names, etc... (all of those seem impractical from a UX perspective).

Comment: If the user starts from an Establishment view, then clicks on perhaps an "Add Happies" link, you could pass in the establishment id. Or if they go straight to adding "Happies", they have to indicate an Establishment somehow. What exactly does "impractical from a UX perspective" mean? There are well established and common paradigms.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely say use a dropdown. There's nothing wrong with that from a UX perspective. Then simply send the `establishment_id` through underneath.

So you'll have a select tag, and inside it list the available users. Surprisingly Rails doesn't have a direct helper for this but it's easy to code the html yourself:

```
<select id="user_establishment_id" name="user[establishment_id]">
  <% Establishment.all.each do |establishment| %>
    <option value="<%= establishment.id %>"><%= establishment.title %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

With this you'll have a simple user-friendly dropdown, and your backend will also be neat and happy.